# download single torrent on multiple platforms without duplicating (or at least minimizing duplication)

Tags: windows, android, bittorrent

I've found similar requests to this, but not quite the same.

I have a laptop and an Android, sometimes one has WiFi, sometimes the other, sometimes both.

I want to initiate a torrent download (don't really care what client to use, although currently using utorrent on PC and atorrent on Android) on one device and then at a later date continue the download on the other device without duplicating content. Once I have 100% of the data I want to recombine into usable files.

E.g.

1. I begin linux.iso.torrent from my PC, it gets to 30% when I have to leave the Internet. My pc client relates information regarding which data has already been downloaded, either to be stored online in a 'account' and then downloaded by Android or directly communicated via USB sync or WiFi. Note I do not want the actual data transferred in this way, just information about which data has already been downloaded.
2. The next day I am in a cafe with access to wifi but don't have my laptop. Android either already knows by USB/WiFi syncing or checks against my account online to determine which parts of linux.iso.torrent have already been downloaded on my pc and only downloads the remaining 70%
3. I connect laptop and Android and combine the data downloaded by each into a complete linux.iso which can be mounted/burnt.

Ideally this means I can maintain a single download list and if either of my devices have Internet they will check what is not yet downloaded and continue. If both are connected one (laptop) will begin downloading as many files as it's max simultaneous download setting allow, the other (Android) will start at the next file in the list.

Comment: Normally where it left off will work based on the previous data block processed in the source file and packet checksum verification received for the lastest packet before interruption or suspend state. I believe that downloading a file in different instance with out previous checksum info is not possible

Comment: so I just need to communicate checksum data between the systems? could I transfer this data locally? or keep such info in a synced folder? can checksum be stored separate to download data?

Answer (score 0):

Normally where it left off will work based on the previous data block processed in the source file and packet checksum verification received for the lastest packet before interruption or suspend state. I believe that downloading a file in different instance with out previous checksum info is not possible

Comment: I'm confused, you wrote this and above user edited it? so I just need to communicate checksum data between the systems? could I transfer this data locally? or keep such info in a synced folder? can checksum be stored separate to download data?

Answer (score 0):

I once tried such a thing where I downloaded 58.6% of Fedora.iso (torrent) in Ubuntu and later when I booted to Win7 (dual boot laptop), I just copied the entire download location directory and ran the torrent again in windows 7 and it worked!

So all you need to do is to copy the iso file (incompletely downloaded) to the android phone and vice-versa each time there is a new byte downloaded and you were offline. AFAIK there is no such program to do this job too. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: this doesn't really help. the ultimate goal is to maintain a single download list  that any system connected to my 'account' or synced locally (happy with either solution) can work on whenever it has decent Internet connection. I don't want to be transferring actual download data between systems (until combining the completed download at the end) - just information *about* the download data...